# Association table population is working but fetching is not populating the associated data

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am setting up a many to many association between student and courses in Java and Spring Boot. The association table is getting filled while saving data. However, while fetching students data, courses data is not getting fetched. I have given fetch type as EAGER, but still it's not working. Here is my Student entity and Course entity.

Student entity:

```java
package com.sij.demospringboot.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentEntity  implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Name is mandatory")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable = true, name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    private Set<CourseEntity> courses = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Course entity:

```java
package com.sij.demospringboot.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CourseEntity  implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Course Name is mandatory")
    private String courseName;
    
    @Column(nullable = true, name = "course_dur")
    private String courseDuration;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<StudentEntity> students = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Here are my students table, courses table and student_courses (association) table

[image: Students table]

[image: Courses table]

[image: Association table]

Saving works, but while trying to fetch student data, courses data is coming as an empty set.

Please help me in understanding why it may be the case and how to solve it.

Comment: A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data _and the expected result_.

Comment: Do you expect a SQL answer? If not, you can remove the <sql> tag.

Comment: On a side note you should be careful with mutual eager loading. In your current setup you're basically telling to load all courses for a student, all students for a course etc. - this may end up loading all students and all courses even if you just wanted one. Better use lazy loading by default and put a fetch operation/hint into your loading code.